# Trying to remove crafting recipes but UniDict adds them back

Tags: minecraft

I am trying to remove some furnace crafting recipes with CraftTweaker, like so:

```
val IngotArray = [
    <minecraft:iron_ingot>,
    <minecraft:gold_ingot>,
    <advancedrocketry:productingot>,
    <advancedrocketry:productingot:1>,
    <immersiveengineering:metal:5>,
    <matteroverdrive:tritanium_ingot>,
    <mekanism:ingot:1>,
    <nuclearcraft:ingot:3>,
    <nuclearcraft:ingot:5>,
    <nuclearcraft:ingot:6>,
    <nuclearcraft:ingot:7>,
    <nuclearcraft:ingot:9>,
    <nuclearcraft:ingot:10>,
    <nuclearcraft:ingot_oxide>,
    <nuclearcraft:ingot_oxide:1>,
    <techguns:itemshared:85>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:129>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:130>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:131>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:132>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:133>,
    <libvulpes:productingot:7>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:164>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:163>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:162>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:161>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:160>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:136>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:135>,
    <thermalfoundation:material:134>,
    <tconstruct:ingots:1>,
    <tconstruct:ingots>
] as IItemStack[];

for item in IngotArray{
    furnace.remove(item);
}
```

Most of them work, but some don't. The Thermal Foundation metals here stay the same. I've done some reading and found out that UniDict messes with recipes after CraftTweaker does, and re-adds a whole bunch of them. I tried fiddling around with UniDict's config but nothing seems to change anything besides disabling the entire integration, and I don't want that.

Does anybody know a way to get the configs correct, or make UniDict operate before CraftTweaker?

Answer (score 0):

unidict adds its recipes way after crafttweaker, you should go to the config file for unidict and find the string for recipe remove list
"S:recipeToRemoveList"

Comment: Yes I saw that, but I couldn't find what exactly to put in that field. Do you know the syntax? IE, how to refer to a specific recipe with a string?